# ¿Cómo leer una línea específica en archivo XML?

Tags: android

Quiero saber alguna forma o método para agregar un fragmento de codigo adicional en un archivo xml.
Ejemplo: El siguiente código es mi archivo xml

```
<user_config>
algunos elementos aqui
</user_config>

<resources>
quiero escribir algunos adicionales aqui 
</resources>
```

La idea es que el metodo busque la etiqueta `<resources>` y dentro de ella, agrege el texto que yo defina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando JSOUP, una librería para parsear xml en java:

https://github.com/jhy/jsoup

```
String xml = "<user_config> algunos elementos aqui </user_config> <resources> quiero escribir algunos adicionales aqui </resources>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
for (Element e : doc.select("user_config")) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: En un String no se puede colocar "<>"

Comment: Claro que puedes poner <> y cualquier carácter unicode, es probable que debas escaparlo, pero.. si se puede

Answer (score 1):

Pues el paquete `javax.xml.parsers.*` contiene todo lo que necesitas para ayudarte, aquí te dejo un ejemplillo para que veas como seria la cosa.

```
try {
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Trip/"+tripID+".trip";  
        File file = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

        // Cambiamos el contenido del nodo
        Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("resources").item(0);
        nodes.setTextContent(newname);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        //Guardamos el archivo modificado
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Aqui donde dice tripID colocaria la ruta de donde esta el archivos xml ? y en la linea que dice  `Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("resources").item(0);`  debo colocar el texto que quiero agregar ?

Comment: La variable filePath es donde deberkas colocar la ruta al .xml q quieres editar, y el metodo nodes.setTextContent() es donde debes meter es texto q quieras agregar.